# Documents open in Office 2010 on PC with both Office 2010 and Office 2019

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2019

I have installed Office 2019 on my Windows 10 Pro build 1903 laptop. Later, due to some circumstances, I had to install Office 2010.

Whenever I open Word, Excel or PowerPoint files they open with Office 2010 instead of Office 2019. The **Open With...** option isn't even displaying the name of Word/Excel/Powerpoint 2019. Even after selecting the **Look for an app on the PC** option, when I navigate to the Word 2019 Application (*winword.exe*), it opens up with Office 2010.

How can I fix this?

---

Comment: Why not just uninstall Office 2010?

Comment: If you want Office 2019 to be the default application, you should uninstall both products, install Office 2010 then install Office 2019.  Are you sure you are using the correct path to `winword.exe`?

Answer (score 2):

Co-installations of Office 2010 and 2019 are supported according to the Microsoft support article [Install and use different versions of Office on the same PC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/install-and-use-different-versions-of-office-on-the-same-pc-6ebb44ce-18a3-43f9-a187-b78c513788bf), but you must meet several requirements, the relevant one being:

> Install earlier versions of Office first. For example, install Office 2010 before installing Office 2019...

Based on your question you installed Office 2010 second, which is why you're having problems. Correct this by running a repair installation of Office 2019. If that fails, uninstall Office 2019, make sure Office 2010 is working properly, then reinstall Office 2019.

### Additional Information

- [Office 2010 and Office 2013, 2016, or 2019 side by side](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/office-2010-and-office-2013-2016-or-2019-side-by-side-eb569695-ce97-4841-831e-236f095f7803?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the default program for opening documents has been changed to Office 2010. Try to set Office 2019 as default. Then you can open your documents in Office 2019.

Comment: You could give directions for setting the default. One method is to run a repair of Office 2019.